# Get the official American time zone in PHP?

Tags: php, timezone

I have account stored in my database and I have each account state on file, from there I want to link each account to a timezone based on the account state.

so if the account's state is California then the timezone will be "America/Los_Angeles"

More, I want to break down the time zone that is provided at this page http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.america.php by
Atlantic
Eastern
Central
Mountain
Pacific
Alaska
Hawaii - Aleutian

Now I will be able to sort my data based on 7 time zones and also I can have all my account linked to a timezone so I can determine their time zone.

So My question
1) How can I figure out what state is linked to what timezone. (example: California = "America/Los_Angeles")

2) Which timezone are linked to what timezone category. (example: California = Pacific)

Comment: Do `PHP date timezones` search in Google, you'll get the list. *Literally*. I don't know what you mean by *the* official timezone, there's seven or eight depending on which states you count, plus daylight savings, non-daylight savings. Right now the main ones are probably Eastern, Central, Mountain and Pacific.

Comment: To reiterate - what do you mean by "the main ones".  If you are looking for those defined by law, you can review [15 USC §260-267](http://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/15/chapter-6/subchapter-IX).   [§263](http://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/15/263) in particular.  But this is not very helpful for computing.  PHP uses the IANA/Olson timezone database, which does have abbreviations closely matching the legal names.  If you want to see it visually, [look here](http://www.time.gov/images/US_time_zones.gif).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't thought this through.

Many US states have multiple time zones.  For example, South Dakota has both Mountain and Central time zones.

[image: South Dakota Time Zone Map]

If you desire to resolve a location to a time zone, you will need a much more granular location.  Ideally, a latitude and longitude.  If you don't have one, you can approximate the centroid lat/lon of a zip code, and then use that against any of many various services or databases that will resolve that to a time zone.  But be very careful, not all zip codes represent physical locations, and zip codes change frequently.

Comment: Thanks for that tip, I do have the zip code for every account, so where can I pass that agins to get the time zone?

Comment: There are lots of ways to do this, and its been [asked](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8842153/634824) [many](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2456324/634824) [times](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15304198/634824) [before](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11354490/634824).   Probably the easiest way is with the Google APIs for [GeoCoding](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/) and [TimeZones](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/timezone/)

Comment: Very Very nice. I guess my last question will be, will TimeZones class handle the daylight saving automatically? or I  have to do extra calculation for that? so If I link every account with a time zone using google GeoCoding, then when i do new DateTime(some_date, new DateTimeZone(account_time_zone) ); this will automaticly handles the daylight saving?  Thanks

Comment: That's where you will use the PHP time zone functions.  For example, [see this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-timezone-set.php).

Answer (score 1):

It's always best to go to the source:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.america.php

For all timezones:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php

If you read down the page on the first link, someone was nice enough to make an array if you need the abbreviations:

```
$aTimeZones = array(
  'America/Puerto_Rico'=>'AST',
  'America/New_York'=>'EDT',
  'America/Chicago'=>'CDT',
  'America/Boise'=>'MDT',
  'America/Phoenix'=>'MST',
  'America/Los_Angeles'=>'PDT',
  'America/Juneau'=>'AKDT',
  'Pacific/Honolulu'=>'HST',
  'Pacific/Guam'=>'ChST',
  'Pacific/Samoa'=>'SST',
  'Pacific/Wake'=>'WAKT',
);
```

Comment: Yes I have seen that prior posting my question but that gives a list of everything, I only need the main once